# How to save an integer as taxonomy term?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, date

I've written a custom meta box such that taxonomy terms will always be integers (Unix timestamps), and I'd like to keep them as integers so I can sort these posts by their Unix Timestamp in the post_type's archive. The problem is that if an integer is passed to the `$term` parameter in `wp_set_object_terms()`, WordPress assumes it is the ID of the term you want to set, not the value. The only way to get the integer to set is to pass it as a string, which means the callback looks something like this:

```
// input data from the meta box
$year = 2013;
$month = "January";
$day = 12;
$date strval(strtotime($month . ' ' . $day . ' ' . $year)); // Convert the string to 
                                                            // an integer and then back 
                                                            // to a string!

wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $date, $taxonomy);
```

Which is fine, except now I have numbers stored as strings in the database when I wanted numbers. When I write the archive page I'll have to convert them back to numbers before running `date()` to display them. It'd be nice to save some of those keystrokes.

Ideas?

Comment: I am not 100% certain but I don't think that is technically possible in WP. As for me custom field is better storage for timestamps than term.

Comment: Why don’t you just add a space at the end of the number? The term is stored in the db as a string anyway.